# Изменение размера окна с помощью мышки

Tags: c++, qt, resize

Создал окно без рамки. Сейчас написал код который работает только при увеличении размеров окна, если пытаться уменьшить то получается *белиберда* или окно вовсе крашится. Возможно неправильно просчитываю...

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    //События для resize окна
    if(acceptDrag)
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress && Border != null)
        {
            QMouseEvent* mouse_event = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if (mouse_event->button() & Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                dragStartPosition = mouse_event->pos();
                dragStartGeometry = geometry();
                StartResize = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        {
            QMouseEvent* mouse_event = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if(!(mouse_event->button() & Qt::LeftButton))
            {
                if(mouse_event->x() <= 3 && mouse_event->y() <= 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeFDiagCursor);
                    Border = topleft;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->x() >= width() - 3 && mouse_event->y() <= 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeBDiagCursor);
                    Border = topright;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->x() <= 3 && mouse_event->y() >= height() - 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeBDiagCursor);
                    Border = bottomleft;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->x() >= width() - 3 && mouse_event->y() >= height() - 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeFDiagCursor);
                    Border = bottomright;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->x() <= 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeHorCursor);
                    Border = left;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->x() >= width() - 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeHorCursor);
                    Border = right;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->y() <= 3)
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeVerCursor);
                    Border = top;
                }
                else if(mouse_event->y() >= height() - 3 && mouse_event->x() <= width())
                {
                    setCursor(Qt::SizeVerCursor);
                    Border = bottom;
                }
                else {
                    unsetCursor();
                    Border = null;
                }
            }

            if(StartResize)
            {
                switch(Border)
                {
                case topleft:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left() - (dragStartPosition.x() - mouse_event->x()),
                                dragStartGeometry.top() - (dragStartPosition.y() - mouse_event->y()),
                                dragStartGeometry.width() + (dragStartPosition.x() - mouse_event->x()),
                                height() + (dragStartPosition.y() - mouse_event->y()));
                    dragStartGeometry = geometry();
                    break;

                case bottomleft:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left() - (dragStartPosition.x() - mouse_event->x()),
                                dragStartGeometry.top(),
                                dragStartGeometry.width() + (dragStartPosition.x() - mouse_event->x()),
                                mouse_event->y());
                    dragStartGeometry = geometry();
                    break;

                case topright:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left(),
                                dragStartGeometry.top() - (dragStartPosition.y() - mouse_event->y()),
                                mouse_event->x(),
                                height() + (dragStartPosition.y() - mouse_event->y()));
                    dragStartGeometry = geometry();
                    break;

                case bottomright:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left(),
                                dragStartGeometry.top(),
                                mouse_event->x(),
                                mouse_event->y());
                    break;

                case left:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left() - (dragStartPosition.x() - mouse_event->x()),
                                dragStartGeometry.top(),
                                dragStartGeometry.width() + (dragStartPosition.x() - mouse_event->x()),
                                height());
                    dragStartGeometry = geometry();
                    break;

                case right:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left(),
                                dragStartGeometry.top(),
                                mouse_event->x(),
                                height());
                    break;

                case top:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left(),
                                dragStartGeometry.top() - (dragStartPosition.y() - mouse_event->y()),
                                dragStartGeometry.width(),
                                height() + (dragStartPosition.y() - mouse_event->y()));
                    dragStartGeometry = geometry();
                    break;

                case bottom:
                    setGeometry(dragStartGeometry.left(),
                                dragStartGeometry.top(),
                                width(),
                                mouse_event->y());
                    break;

                case null:
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        StartResize = false;
    return false;
}
```

В заголовке MainWindow описаны:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);
enum sBorder{topleft, left, bottomleft, bottom,
             bottomright, right, topright, top, null} Border = null;
bool StartResize = false;
QPoint dragStartPosition;
QRect dragStartGeometry;
```

В конструкторе MainWindow:

```
setMouseTracking(true);
installEventFilter(this);
```

Заранее спасибо! Готов выслушать любые идеи)

Comment: Вы вручную пытаетесь реагировать на попытки мышкой изменить размер окна? Какую задачу вы при этом хотите решить? Почему не разрешить окну менять размеры стандартными средствами (через свойства окна в дизайнере форм, например)

Comment: @vegorov я создаю свое окно без рамки (Qt::FramelessWindowHint) вместо того чтобы отрисовывать новую рамку я использую 4 titlebar (по сторонам) и я пытаюсь создать возможность растягивать окно за края этих titlebar

Comment: Ок. А зачем. Исходная задача какая ?

Comment: @vegorov  Не устраивает рамка которая предоставляется ОСью... пытаюсь создать полностью свое оформление... Я знаю ещё есть QSizeGrip, но это не совсем то что нужно....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создадим пустой `ui` диалога. В качестве границ диалога будем использовать `QLabel`'лы. Для каждой стороны и угла соотвественно `Top, Left, Bottom, Rigth, TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight`. Минимальный размер угловых лэйблов установим `4х4`, остальных `2x2`. По центру создать `QWidget` с именем `central`. Скомпоновать их следующим образом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем компоновкам выставить `margin` и `spacing` в `0`. В основной компоновке свойству соотношения размеров виджетов внутри компоновки `layoutStretch` выставить `1,1000,1`

Далее объявим класс, реализующий нашу `ui`.

```
#include "ui_DialogResizeBase.h"

class ResizeDialogBase : public QDialog, public Ui::DialogResizeBase
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //отображает курсор в соответствии с QLabel
    void setSideCursor(int);  
    //Вычисляет новый размер
    void changeSize(int, QMouseEvent*);
public:
    ResizeDialogBase(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
};
```

Конструктор

```
    enum {
        TOP,
        BOTTOM,
        RIGHT,
        LEFT,
        TOP_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        TOP_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT
    };

ResizeDialogBase::
ResizeDialogBase(QWidget *parent):
    QDialog (parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    //устанавливаем фильтр событий для каждого QLabel
    Top->installEventFilter(this);
    Bottom->installEventFilter(this);
    Right->installEventFilter(this);
    Left->installEventFilter(this);
    LefTop->installEventFilter(this);
    RightBottom->installEventFilter(this);
    RightTop->installEventFilter(this);
    LeftBottom->installEventFilter(this);

    //Определяем свойство side для идентификации стороны
    //можно сделать в дизайнере
    Top->setProperty("side", TOP);
    Bottom->setProperty("side", BOTTOM);
    Right->setProperty("side", RIGHT);
    Left->setProperty("side", LEFT);
    LefTop->setProperty("side", TOP_LEFT);
    RightBottom->setProperty("side", BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    RightTop->setProperty("side", TOP_RIGHT);
    LeftBottom->setProperty("side", BOTTOM_LEFT);

    //Нажата ли левая кнопка мыши
    setProperty("pressed", false);
    //Обрамление диалога
    setStyleSheet("QDialog {\n  border: 1px solid red;\n}");
}
```

Фильтр событий

```
bool
ResizeDialogBase::
eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::Enter: setSideCursor(watched->property("side").toInt()); break;
        case QEvent::Leave: setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor); break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            if( static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
                setProperty("pressed", true); break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            if( static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
                setProperty("pressed", false); break;
        case QEvent::MouseMove: changeSize(watched->property("side").toInt(), static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)); break;
        default: break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Установка курсора

```
void
ResizeDialogBase::
setSideCursor(int side)
{
    switch (side) {
        case TOP:      case BOTTOM:       setCursor(Qt::SizeVerCursor);   break;
        case RIGHT:    case LEFT:         setCursor(Qt::SizeHorCursor);   break;
        case TOP_LEFT: case BOTTOM_RIGHT: setCursor(Qt::SizeFDiagCursor); break;
        case TOP_RIGHT:case BOTTOM_LEFT:  setCursor(Qt::SizeBDiagCursor); break;
    }
}
```

Изменение размеров диалога

```
void
ResizeDialogBase::
changeSize(int side, QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(property("pressed").toBool()) {
        auto geom = geometry();
        auto x = event->globalX();
        auto y = event->globalY();
        static auto minW = minimumWidth();
        static auto minH = minimumHeight();
        switch (side) {
            case TOP: {
                geom.setY(minH < geom.height() ? y : geom.y());
                geom.setHeight(geom.height() + (geom.y()-y));
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            }
            case BOTTOM:
                geom.setHeight(geom.height() + event->y());
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                geom.setWidth(geom.width()+event->x());
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            case LEFT: {
                geom.setX(minW < geom.width() ? x : geom.x());
                geom.setWidth(geom.width()+(geom.x()-x));
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            }
            case TOP_LEFT: {
                geom.setX(minW < geom.width() ? x : geom.x());
                geom.setY(minH < geom.height() ? y : geom.y());
                geom.setWidth(geom.width()+(geom.x()-x));
                geom.setHeight(geom.height() + (geom.y()-y));
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            }
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                geom.setWidth(geom.width()+event->x());
                geom.setHeight(geom.height() + event->y());
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            case TOP_RIGHT: {
                geom.setY(minH < geom.height() ? y : geom.y());
                geom.setWidth(geom.width()+event->x());
                geom.setHeight(geom.height() + (geom.y()-y));
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            }
            case BOTTOM_LEFT: {
                geom.setX(minW < geom.width() ? x : geom.x());
                geom.setWidth(geom.width()+(geom.x()-x));
                geom.setHeight(geom.height() + event->y());
                setGeometry(geom);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Можно использовать как базовый класс для кастомных диалогов, требующих изменения размеров.